# Cannot kill self-firing intinite loop PHP Apache processes

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, httpd

I've fired a PHP file by mistake that calls itself and creates an infinite loop.

Now I'm trying to purge these processes, and I've done the following:

- tried to kill the processes with `kill pid`, but more and more processes are created indefinitely
- restarted Apache, this kills the main process and all the children, but as soon as I start Apache, they are all back
- reinstalling Apache

I'm clueless as to what I can do next.

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE: This is the part of the code that causes the script to call itself over and over**

```
function run_background_process($url, $params) {

  // do a normal cURL POST
  $cmd = 'curl -X POST ';
  // append the URL to the script
  $cmd .= $url;
  // add any variables that needs to be passed to the target script
  $cmd .= ' -d "' . $params . '"';
  // run it in the background so it does not affect page load
  $cmd .= " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"; 
  // execute
  exec($cmd, $output, $exit); 
  return $exit == 0;

}
```

So, the script calls itself using cuRL (`run_background_process(site_url)` is called earlier in the script)

Comment: Are you using php-fpm ?

Comment: Hello @user449299, no I do not

Comment: I hope `$url` and `$params` are sanitized at all call sites, otherwise this is vulnerable to shell injection.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @b0fh, this is just a test script. I need to sanitize these params when implementing it into the production system.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the PHP file. It will then be unable to call itself.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesnt seem to work. The process list just keeps on growing even though I've changed the filename(s) completely. To be sure of this I renamed the file and let it be for a few hours - I come back and check the process list with ps faux - ther is still around 200 Apache child processes working. And if I restart Apache, they all come back (around 400)

Comment: I see that all of these processes has the same command: `\_ /usr/sbin/httpd`, while the main httpd process' command is `/usr/sbin/httpd`. Is it somehow possible to target and close all of the processes that contains the command `\_ /usr/sbin/httpd`?

Comment: Oh, you run PHP as an Apache module? Then just stop Apache.

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing, sorry if it isn't clear in the post above. As I previously stated, stopping Apache kills these processes, but when I restart the Apache service module then a ton of these Apache child processes are back.

Comment: So, why do you think that these Apache processes have anything to do with your PHP script?

Comment: Because the script itself sends an email to my Gmail account each time it's executed, and I get tons of emails from this script to my Gmail account when the Apache/httpd service is turned on.